# deep link in react SPA correctly falls back to index.html; but afterwards does not navigate back to deep link

Tags: reactjs, apache, mod-rewrite, react-router, fallback

I have a CRA (v4) react app 'TheProject' I host on an apache2.4 webserver under the subdirectory:

**/htdocs/site/TheProject**

I have defined a .htaccess file at this location: (and enabled the mod rewrite plugin!)

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html
```

To handle my client-side routing, I'm using react-router (5.2.0), my routing configuration looks like this:

```html
<BrowserRouter basename='site/TheProject'>
<Route exact path="/history" component={History}/>
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
<Route exact path="/">
   <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
</Route>
<BrowserRouter basename={baseName}>
```

Where I redirect root requests to my dashboard component, and use site/TheProject as the basename,
so URLs will be served like this: **[www.thehost.com/site/TheProject/[routing]](http://www.thehost.com/site/TheProject/%5Brouting%5D)**

Expected behavior:

**existing resource on web server:** (1)

thehost.com/site/theproject/xyz  => thehost.com/site/theproject/xyz

**non-existing resource on web server:** (2)

thehost.com/site/theproject/xyz/fpfze => thehost.com/site/theproject/index.html
=> thehost.com/site/theproject/dashboard

**non-existing on server but an existing client side react route:** (3)

thehost.com/site/theproject/history => thehost.com/site/theproject/index.html
=> thehost.com/site/theproject/history

The problem I'm facing now is that (3) does not work as expected: a request to **/history?q=something** will be handled by my apache configuration and will fall back to my index.html hook, but it will not redirect back to **/history?q=something** as expected, instead, it will redirect back to **/dashboard**.

One more interesting thing to note though, is that when the network tab is opened, the request is handled towards **/history?q=something** and the **API request** I do in that History component is executed, meaning the useEffect hook inside the History component was visited!

Comment: Thanks for detailed question, could you please do mention more clearly with samples like FROM which example url TO which example url you want to rewrite by htaccess file? That will help us to understand the question better.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've used the example configuration for apache in the angular documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in how react-router works, coming from a static way of declaring routes in angular, react-router works by 'dynamically' declaring routes

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy

```
<BrowserRouter basename='site/TheProject'>
<Route exact path="/history" component={History}/>
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
<Route exact path="/">
   <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
</Route>
```

was changed into:

```
<BrowserRouter basename='site/TheProject'>
   <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
       <Route exact path="/history" component={History}/>
       <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
       <Redirect to='/' />
   </Switch>
```

where the switch exclusively takes the first match of **only 1 route** of the following list, in order of declaration.